# Unity Launcher disappeared - why?

Tags: unity, panel

Basically, when I press <kbd>Super</kbd> it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the Launcher is missing. I have no idea why this happened.

I have already tried the following:

- removing folders: `~/.compiz-1` and `~/.config/compiz-1` and running `unity --reset`,
- reinstalling Unity with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity`,
- reverting all sidebar settings to defaults in [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/),
- checking that the Unity plugin is enabled in CCSM (as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214529/unity-launcher-has-disappeared)),
- restarting the system.

None of these helped. Do you have any other ideas? How can I find out what happened?

Comment: It seems as if the transparency is set to close to 100%.

Comment: I don't think it's "close to 100%". Running `xwininfo` and selecting place where the launcher should be returns info about the Desktop.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: I found the solution - I had to remove `~/.config/monitors.xml`, that helped.